# Disjoint refinement of a countable set of sets

Tags: infinite-groups, well-orders

Say I have a set $A=\{X_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $X_{n}$ is countable. I need to prove that there exists a disjoint refinement $D=\{D_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of $A$ such that:
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}, D_{n}\subseteq X_{n}$ and $D_{n}$ is infinite and $m < n \Rightarrow D_{m}\cap D_{n}=\emptyset$.

I had two ideas: say that for every $m < n$ we managed to find such $D_{m}$. So, defining $D_{n}=X_{n}\backslash\bigcup_{m<n} D_{m}$, but I can't prove that such $D_{n}$ is infinite.

Another idea I had is defining a well - ordering on each of the $X_{n}$ (possible because of AC) and defining $a_1=min\{x|x\in X_{n}\land x\notin\bigcup_{m<n} D_{m}\}$, but it seems to give the same result.

Is one of my ideas the right way or at least close?

Comment: Your first idea seems like a good start, but if $D_n$ turns out finite, you'll have to "steal" some elements of the earlier $D_i$ which also lie in $X_n$, and move them from the earlier $D_i$ into $D_n$, maintaining infiniteness along the way. I don't know how to it, but you since could have e.g. two of the $X_i$'s equal to each other, a straightforward "throw out all duplicates" strategy doesn't seem like it would work without some fixing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ is countable, we may without loss of generality assume that each $X_n$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$.<sup>1</sup> Let $P=\{\langle \ell_k,m_k\rangle:k\in\Bbb N\}$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. I’ll construct the sets $D_n$ by recursion.

Let $D_n(0)=\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. At stage $k$ let

$$D_n(k+1)=\begin{cases}
D_n(k)\cup\left\{\min\left(X_n\setminus\bigcup_\limits{i\in\Bbb N}D_i(k)\right)\right\},&\text{if }n=\ell_k\\
D_n(k),&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

In other words, if $n=k_\ell$, we add to $D_n$ the first member of $X_n$ that has not yet been assigned to any $D_i$. This is always possible, since $X_{\ell_k}$ is infinite and $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}D_i(k)$ is finite, so the recursive construction goes through to construct $D_n(k)$ for each $n,k\in\Bbb N$.

Now let $D_n=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}D_n(k)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$; clearly $D_n\subseteq X_n$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ the set of $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\ell_k=n$ is infinite, since $P$ includes a pair $\langle n,m\rangle$ for each $m\in\Bbb N$, so $D_n$ is infinite. As it is also clear that the construction produces pairwise disjoint sets $D_n$, we’re done.

<sup>1</sup> To see this, let $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$. $X$ is countably infinite, so there is a bijection $\varphi:X\to\Bbb N$. We can replace each $X_n$ by its image $\varphi[X_n]\subseteq\Bbb N$, find infinite pairwise disjoint subsets $D_n$ of theses images, and then use $\varphi^{-1}$ to carry them back to infinite pairwise disjoint subsets $\varphi^{-1}[D_n]$ of the sets $X_n$.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed, first of all how can I assume that Xn is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$? Second of all how can we define $D_{l_{k}}$ by union of $D_{l_{k}}$ with another set?

Comment: @GalBenAyun: Let $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$; this set is countably infinite, so you can index it as $X=\{x_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$. Then you can simply identify each $X_n$ with the subset $\{k\in\Bbb N:x_k\in X_n\}$ of $\Bbb N$. As for your other question, I wrote that answer assuming that you were at least moderatly familiar with recursive constructions; if you’re not, I’ll have to expand it a bit. The idea is that we’re building each $D_n$ one member at a time. The two instances of $D_{\ell_k}$ in the displayed formula are actually two different partial approximations to the eventual $D_{\ell_k}$.

Comment: @GalBenAyun: And I’ve now significantly expanded the answer in a way that I hope clears up at least some of the confusion.

Comment: First of all this is very helpful. Secondly what does Dn(0) means? Does it mean the first element in the set?

Comment: @GalBenAyun: For each $k\in\Bbb N$ the set $D_n(k)$ is simply the $k$-th approximation to the set $D_n$. I start with $D_n(0)=\varnothing$: before I’ve done anything at all, my approximation to $D_n$ is the empty set. As the recursive construction progresses, I add elements to the sets $D_n$.

Comment: So how is this recursive progression different than the one I suggested? I agree it is more detailed and look more well built, but aren't they identical in their essence? meaning I can't see why the union $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} D_{i}(k)$ is finite, and the set I defined, $\bigcup_{m<n} D_{m}$ isn't necessarily.
I know those question are very basic, but I just started out with those concepts in set theory so I feel like I'm missing on a lot.

Comment: @GalBenAyun: Neither of your ideas (especially the second) is described in enough detail for me to show you exactly where they run into trouble, but in both you seem to be trying to define all of $D_0$, then all of $D_1$, then all of $D_2$, and so on, and that cannot work unless the construction somehow ‘looks ahead’ to leave out things that will be needed in later sets $D_n$.

Comment: The first solution I used induction. Assuming I built $D_{m}$ for each m<n. So, they way I build $D_{n}$ is by $X_{n}\backslash\bigcup_{m<n} D_{m}$
Is there anyway to prove that $X_{n}$ is infinite by the way I defined it? or where does it run into trouble.
And by the way this is the first time I run into approximation of a set. I did encounter approximations of functions before, so I'm not quite sure what it means.

Comment: @GalBenAyun: Your first method fails immediately if $X_0\supseteq X_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ (for instance, of all of the sets $X_n$ are identical): you’ll set $D_0=X_0$ and have nothing left for $D_n$ with $n>0$. \\ Don’t get hung up on the word *approximation*: here I just mean an initial segment of the eventual set $D_n$.

Comment: I think this is what I'm missing - how do you use the set P? I realize its a enumeration of $\mathbb{N} \times\mathbb{N}$, but how do you use it here? 
And how can you determine that $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} D_{i}(k)$ is finite?

Comment: @GalBenAyun: I use $P$ to ensure that each $D_n$ is infinite. The point is that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there are infinitely many pairs in $P$ with first component $n$, so in the recursive construction there are infinitely many $k$ such that $\ell_k=n$, and we add a point to $D_n$ for each of them. $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}D_i(k)$ is finite because each stage of the recursion adds only one point to that union, so in fact I know that that union has exactly $k$ elements.

Comment: Brian, with regard to your D_n map defined recursively, is this some sort of standard construction or you thought of it on the spot. Is there literature that you recommend for a better understanding of this situations? Thanks for your amazing/high-quality (Id say probably the best answerer in Match Exchange) responses!

Comment: @ILoveMath: Thank you. Recursive constructions are common in many parts of mathematics, and I’ve seen ones similar in spirit to this one quite often in set theory and set-theoretic topology and used occasionally them myself. A good grounding in set theory at the advanced undergraduate or beginning graduate level is very helpful, something like what one might get from [Hrbaček & Jech](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/0824779150). But what helps most is seeing such constructions used.

Comment: I wish my teachers had 10% of your lucidness and ability to explain hard math

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your answer and explanations were very helpful. I do try to gain a good grasp on set theory and infinite sets but intuition gets in the way so you really made it clear to me where my idea failed.

Comment: @GalBenAyun: I’m glad that it helped. It can take a while to get comfortable with this sort of argument.